# Adding a source in a gateway

Tags: powerbi

This is the error im facing when trying to add a datasource in a gateway:

> Unable to connect: We encountered an error while trying to connect to
>   . Details: "We could not register this data source for any gateway
>   instances within this cluster. Please find more details below about
>   specific errors for each gateway instance.

```
Activity ID:
66610131-d0fc-4787-9432-36b2bbc95dbb
Request ID:
b9231dc4-dd80-8b86-6301-c171aad3b879
Cluster URI:
https://wabi-south-east-asia-redirect.analysis.windows.net
Status code:
400
Error Code:    
DMTS_PublishDatasourceToClusterErrorCode
Time:
Wed Oct 17 2018 12:48:44 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time)
Version:
13.0.6980.207
434Gateway:
Invalid connection credentials.
Underlying error code:
-2147467259
Underlying error message:
The credentials provided for the File source are invalid. (Source at c:\users\rohan\documents\latest 2018\sara\new folder\2018_sales.xls.)
DM_ErrorDetailNameCode_UnderlyingHResult:
-2147467259
Microsoft.Data.Mashup.CredentialError.DataSourceKind:
File
Microsoft.Data.Mashup.CredentialError.DataSourcePath:
c:\users\rohan\documents\latest 2018\sara\new folder\2018_sales.xls
Microsoft.Data.Mashup.CredentialError.Reason:
AccessUnauthorized
Microsoft.Data.Mashup.MashupSecurityException.DataSources:
[{"kind":"File","path":"c:\\users\\rohan\\documents\\latest 2018\\sara\\new folder\\2018_sales.xls"}]
Microsoft.Data.Mashup.MashupSecurityException.Reason:
AccessUnauthorized
Troubleshoot connection problems
```

Comment: It is a good idea to point out the most noticeable lines you think. People can understand better.